# fsck valid option is invalid

Tags: terminal, fsck, sd-card

I have a corrupted micro SD card which I accidentally pulled out. I want to search & fix any errors with **fsck** utility.

```
$ umount /dev/mmcblk0
$ fsck --help
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
fsck.ext3: invalid option -- 'h'
Usage: fsck.ext3 [-panyrcdfktvDFV] [-b superblock] [-B blocksize]
        [-l|-L bad_blocks_file] [-C fd] [-j external_journal]
        [-E extended-options] [-z undo_file] device

Emergency help:
 -p                   Automatic repair (no questions)
 -n                   Make no changes to the filesystem
 -y                   Assume "yes" to all questions
 -c                   Check for bad blocks and add them to the badblock list
 -f                   Force checking even if filesystem is marked clean
 -v                   Be verbose
 -b superblock        Use alternative superblock
 -B blocksize         Force blocksize when looking for superblock
 -j external_journal  Set location of the external journal
 -l bad_blocks_file   Add to badblocks list
 -L bad_blocks_file   Set badblocks list
 -z undo_file         Create an undo file

$ fsck /dev/mmcblk0 
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
exfatfsck 1.2.6
Checking file system on /dev/mmcblk0.
File system version           1.0
Sector size                 512 bytes
Cluster size                128 KB
Volume size                  59 GB
Used space                   25 GB
Available space              35 GB
ERROR: unknown entry type 0x86.
ERROR: cluster 0x111ee of file 'expunged' is not allocated.
Totally 260 directories and 3182 files.
File system checking finished. ERRORS FOUND: 2.

$ fsck -p /dev/mmcblk0
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
exfatfsck 1.2.6
fsck.exfat: invalid option -- 'p'
Usage: fsck.exfat [-V] <device>
```

Why is `-p` option is invalid when it says in help that it is `Automatic repair (no questions)`?
How do I fix my SD card then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the second line of the output in both cases. `fsck --help` used `fsck.ext3` (the default on your system) and displayed the options valid for that tool, but `fsck -p /dev/mmcblk0` used `exfatfsck` since that’s what’s appropriate for your SD card.

Unfortunately `exfatfsck` [can’t repair errors](https://github.com/relan/exfat/issues/3), it can only report them. So run

```
fsck /dev/mmcblk0
```

to see if there are any errors; if there are you’ll need some other strategy to repair the file system:

- use another operating system with tools capable of repairing the file system (Windows?);
- or on Linux, copy all your files somewhere else and reformat the card.